# Convert oracle date to another date format using php language

Tags: php, oracle

I am extracting date from the oracle database in this format: 31-DEC-68, then I use PHP to convert it to date like this: 'Y-m-d'. it's working fine for me for dates after 2000 otherwise it gives a wrong date for example this date :31-DEC-68 converted to 2068-12-31, it should be 1968-12-31.

this is a sample of my code:

```
$query = "select * from my_table";
$stid = oci_parse($connection, $query);
oci_execute($stid);
while (oci_fetch($stid)) {  
    $dateVariable = oci_result($stid, 'date_field_from_oracle'); 
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: **NEVER** store date values as strings, use proper `DATE` data type. Actually there is no other solution for your problem. You basically invented the "[Y2K-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) version 2"

Comment: A date value (supposed it is really a `DATE` value) in Oracle does not have any format, it is stored as internal byte value. What did you try? Convert a `DATE` in Oracle to a string, and then try to convert it back again into a date? Please provide your code, the actual result and the desired result.

Comment: I read from a view from the oracle server, I contacted the responsible person for the server and i see a screenshot from the date returned , it's actually the format i want, but when i call it using php script i get the mentioned format:  31-DEC-68

Comment: i put a sample of my code if this will help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me finally, I used:

```
TO_CHAR(date_field_from_oracle, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

it gives the correct date format: 31-12-1968

Thanks a lot

Comment: That's not what you have asked for. You asked for `1968-12-31`, which would be `TO_CHAR(date_field_from_oracle, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. Better retrieve a `DATE` value and format output with `DateTime::format()` (if possible, I am not so familiar with php).  Anyway, in best case it should be up to the end-user which format he/she likes to get in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for a moment that the date column is really stored as a `DATE` in the database, don't use `select *` in your query: this is generally considered sloppy anyway, and in your case in particular you should be using the `to_char()` function to explicitly define the format in which you want the date returned.

Try something like the following:

```
select to_char(date_field,'YYYY-MM-DD'), other_field1, other_field2 from my_table
```

Then you shouldn't have to do an additional format conversion in PHP or  worry about default session parameters. In general you should *always* define your expected columns and return formats explicitly in your SQL, as default formats may change between tools and sessions (as you're seeing already - that's most likely why the DBAs query results look different that yours), and to be able to identify which code is directly affected by changes to the underlying table (like changes to column names, addition or removal of columns, etc.).

Comment: The final output format and localization of a date value should be done preferably by the front-end client according to end-user preferences, i.e. at the latest possible stage. By using `TO_CHAR(..., 'YYYY-MM-DD')` you enforce a specific output format where the end user may not familiar with it.

Comment: I agree, assuming that the code handles the date as a date datatype - a better solution all around - but that does not appear to be the case here. Wherever/however the date is converted to a string, that conversion should be explicitly defined and not left to defaults that may change by session or environment or break the code.

Comment: Yes, looks like php is not able to retrieve native `DATE` value from Oracle. Then, of course it is the best solution to use a fix format like `YYYY-MM-DD`